# JavaFX TableView: can I keep column data as a float so it's sortable and format/show it as a string somehow?

Tags: java, javafx

This is what I currently have:

```
    fileSizeColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
        SimpleStringProperty stringProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();


        float sizeInMegabytes = (float)cellData.getValue().fileSizeProperty().getValue() / 1024 / 1024;
        sizeInMegabytes = round(sizeInMegabytes, 2);

        stringProperty.setValue(sizeInMegabytes + "mb");
        return stringProperty;
    });

    fileSizeColumn.setComparator((t1, t2) -> {

        float f1 = Float.parseFloat(t1.replaceAll("[^0-9.]",""));
        float f2 = Float.parseFloat(t2.replaceAll("[^0-9.]",""));
        return Float.compare(f1,f2);

    });
```

So there's a property for file size that is a originally a `long` (it's in bytes). To get this in my table I convert it to megabytes, round to two decimal places, then add `"mb"` on the end. I have then made a custom comparator that strips the `"mb"` off the end. I ultimately will have this be in KB and GB depending on size, which will make the comparator clunky (if `endsWith("mb")` do this, if `endsWith("kb")` do this etc).

What I would like is to add the long to the table as a `SimpleLongProperty` but somehow format how it is displayed.

So is there any option to say "here is the actual value behind-the-scenes which should be used for sorting, now take this value, divide it by a number, and add the string 'mb' onto the end of it when actually displaying it"?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you keep the data in it's original form in the `cellValueFactory` and customize the `TableCell` using the `cellFactory` to customize, how the data is displayed:

```
public static String fileSizeToText(long fileSize) {
     return round(((float) fileSize) / 1024 / 1024, 2) + "mb";
}

...

TableColumn<MyClass, Number> fileSizeColumn = ...
fileSizeColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().fileSizeProperty());
fileSizeColumn.setCellFactory(c -> new TableCell<MyClass, Number>() {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || item == null) {
             setText(null);
        } else {
             setText(fileSizeToText(item.longValue()));
        }
    }

});
```

No `Comparator` is needed in this approach, since `Long` implements `Comparable` in a way that suits your needs.

Comment: This is exactly how I expected it to work yet I got it wrong at the last lap somehow. Thank you very much for your answer, it's working perfectly now